# tfsbuild in a powershell script to run concurrently

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild

i have to build several solutions for a single deliverable. So i have a series of tfsbuild commands to execute.   is there a way to have these builds build concurrently?   the tfs server has multiple controllers and build agents.  i don't want to wait for each one to finish individually to finish the job.  i currently have a single powershell script trigger all of the builds... and i'd rather not have separate scripts to do this.  i presume if i separate the builds to different scripts that might solve my issue, but is there an alternative?

Comment: Check out [PowerShell Jobs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs.aspx).

Comment: @SamuelProut You should put that in an answer so we can vote it and he can mark this thing done.  That's a good use for jobs.

Comment: tx, yes PowerShell Jobs is what i needed.